# Core Data, Xcode 4.5 and Creating Fetched Requests in the Data Model

Tags: ios, database, xcode, core-data, xcode4

I am trying to understand Core Data and it is slow progress but I am slowly getting there.  One thing that is puzzling me is how to create a Fetched Request in the data model editor that pulls records with the criteria from across a relationship.

e.g. I have two entities "Main Category" and "Sub Category" which has a one to many relationship.

I can't see how I can create a Fetched Request in the editor to select Sub Categories that match "SOME_SUB" whos main category is "SOME_MAIN".  in SQL this is trivial but I am banging my head here.

I can see the apple documentation that shows how to create a Fetched Request via code here https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFetching.html but I want to keep the Fetched Requests in the data model view instead.

Any hints?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When viewing your data model, select the entity you want to create the fetch request for. Select the "Editor" menu item from the menu bar -> Add Fetch Request.